# Apollo GraphQL - Is it possible to do the same query requesting different fields?

Tags: android, graphql, apollo, apollo-client, apollo-android

I am using [apollo-android](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android) and I want to know if it is possible to do the following approach:

I have defined a query called `locations` in the `schema.json` of my server. It is defined like this:

```
type locations {
  continents: [Continent!],
  countries: [Country!],
  usaStates: [UsaState!]
}
```

Trying this query in the Playground works perfectly and it returns the continents, countries and usaStates. This is the query I define in the Playground:

```
query getLocations {
  locations {
    continents {
      name
      code
    }
    countries {
      name
      code
    }
    usaStates {
      code
      name
    }
  }
}
```

And of course, if I only request que continents, it only returns the continents:

```
query getLocations {
  locations {
    continents {
      name
      code
    }
}
```

My question is if it's possible to do the same in the client part. When I define the query in the `api.graphql` file of my Android project, I do it like this:

```
query getLocations {
  locations {
    continents {
      name
      code
    }
    countries {
      code
      name
    }
    usaStates {
      code
      name
    }
  }
}
```

And then, when I call it in the code, the result contains the continents, countries and usaStates:

```
GetLocationsQuery builder = GetLocationsQuery.builder().build();

api.query(builder)
    .enqueue(new ApolloCall.Callback<GetLocationsQuery.Data>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NotNull com.apollographql.apollo.api.Response<GetLocationsQuery.Data> response) {
                apiListener.onFinish(response);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NotNull ApolloException e) {
                Log.v("APOLLO", e.toString());
                apiListener.onError(e);
            }
        });
```

There is a way to do the same call but defining that I only want the continents instead continents, countries and usaStates?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The specification](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#directives) says:

> The core GraphQL specification includes exactly two directives, which
>   must be supported by any spec-compliant GraphQL server implementation:
>
> - **@include**(if: Boolean) Only include this field in the result if the argument is true.
> - **@skip**(if: Boolean) Skip this field if the argument is true.

`api.graphql` with skip directive:

```
query getLocations($continentsOnly: Boolean) {
  locations {
    continents {
      name
      code
    }
    countries @skip(if: $continentsOnly) {
      code
      name
    }
    usaStates @skip(if: $continentsOnly) {
      code
      name
    }
  }
}
```

Obviously, you will need to specify the value of `continentsOnly`

Comment: Thanks! It works perfect! Only one thing that I had to change of your code. I was getting a GraphQL Validation Failed because the variable $continentsOnly was not initialized. So in the end I had to call it like:  query getLocations($continentsOnly: Boolean = true) { ... }